# Arrange UIscrollView to back

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview

Maybe a huge noob question but i cant seem to figure it out, even after some time googling i cant find out to arrange a scrollview underneeth a navigation bar.

My code:

```
    - (void)loadView {

    UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
    scroll.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    scroll.delegate = self;
    image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Plattegrond DeFabrique schematisch.png"]];
    scroll.contentSize = image.frame.size;
    [scroll addSubview:image];

    scroll.minimumZoomScale = scroll.frame.size.width / image.frame.size.width;
    scroll.maximumZoomScale = 2.0;
    [scroll setZoomScale:scroll.minimumZoomScale];

    self.view = scroll;

}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting the view behind the superview or try sendSubviewToBack.

```
[[self.view superview] insertSubview:scroll belowSubview:self.view];
```

or

```
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:scroll];
```

It sounds like you are just wanting to add the scroll view to the self.view though. Do as the other answer suggest and create the scrollView from the self.view frame then add it to your self.view.

```
UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame]; // Thilina
[self.view addSubview:scroll];
```

Comment: This will cause an infinite recursion because getting `self.view` calls `loadView`.

Comment: well that didnt work: i did this: 
self.view = scroll;
 [self.view sendSubviewToBack:scroll];

Comment: Why are you setting self.view = scroll? Just add the subview to self.view and the scroll view will appear underneath that navBar.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the self.view's frame when creating the ScrollView. This will solve your problem.

```
- (void)loadView {

    UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    scroll.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    scroll.delegate = self;
    image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Plattegrond DeFabrique schematisch.png"]];
    scroll.contentSize = image.frame.size;
    [scroll addSubview:image];

    scroll.minimumZoomScale = scroll.frame.size.width / image.frame.size.width;
    scroll.maximumZoomScale = 2.0;
    [scroll setZoomScale:scroll.minimumZoomScale];

    [self.view addSubView:scroll]; //MarkM

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, weirdly i getting this: http://andrewho.nl/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/iOS-simulatorschermafbeelding-6-mei-2013-23.54.49.png

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing the frame of `[UIScreen mainScreen]` at the time of allocating the UIScrollView , the size of UIScrollView is overlapping the UINavigation . Replace it with

```
UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
```

also rather than replacing the self.view with the scrollView , try to add the scrollView as subview on self.view

```
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

Do the following task in the `viewDidLoad`

Hope it will help you.

Comment: thanks for your help, at the moment i only see half of the nav bar... realy strange